# Reference cycles when using inspect module

Tags: python, garbage-collection, inspect, garbage, reference-cycle

The documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack):

> **Note** Keeping references to frame objects, as found in the first element of the frame records these functions return, can cause your program to create reference cycles. Once a reference cycle has been created, the lifespan of all objects which can be accessed from the objects which form the cycle can become much longer even if Python’s optional cycle detector is enabled. If such cycles must be created, it is important to ensure they are explicitly broken to avoid the delayed destruction of objects and increased memory consumption which occurs.
>
> Though the cycle detector will catch these, destruction of the frames (and local variables) can be made deterministic by removing the cycle in a `finally` clause. This is also important if the cycle detector was disabled when Python was compiled or using `gc.disable()`. For example:
>
> ```
> def handle_stackframe_without_leak():
> frame = inspect.currentframe()
> try:
>     # do something with the frame
> finally:
>     del frame
> ```
>
> If you want to keep the frame around (for example to print a traceback later), you can also break reference cycles by using the `frame.clear()` method.

Which supposedly means that there are two things that have references to each other. What are they exactly?

Can you explain more precisely under which conditions a reference cycle is created? When I do `inspect.currentframe()` without `del frame`? Does the same go for `inspect.stack()`? Any other methods/circumstances?

Comment: I just encountered this issue on my production web service. I used this module to get the line number inside my log processor, and it caused memory leak for any big size web request. Now I use `traceback` instead.